# Ubuntu 16.04 Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro Touchpad 3/4 finger swipe

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics, touchegg

I have a lenovo Yoga 2 Pro running 16.04 and Gnome 3.20.

I'd like to enable 3/4 finger swipe actions:

3 finger swipe left/right = back/forward in browsers(ALT+Left/ALT+Right)

3 Finger swip up/down = switch workspaces or Super Key(Windows key)

4 Finger swipe up/down = show desktop

Those are the ideas i have, at least. However, i have been unable to get 3/4 finger swipes to be recognized at all.

I've instaleed/re-installed different versions of the synaptic driver. I've tried xSwipe, touchegg and another custom script. But literally nothing works, at all.

It's 2016, why this isn't baked right into linux is beyond me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party, and I don't have a Lenovo Yoga, but touchegg works for me on 16.04!

1. Touchegg needs to be started within xprofile with ubuntu 16.04:

   ```
   echo "touchegg &" >> ~/.xprofile
   ```
2. Then you can update the touchegg config file to swipe between desktops with 3 fingers.

   Here is the relavant part of my file `~/.config/touchegg/touchegg.conf`:

   ```
   <gesture type="DRAG" fingers="3" direction="DOWN">
       <action type="SEND_KEYS">Control+Alt+Up</action>
   </gesture>

   <gesture type="DRAG" fingers="3" direction="UP">
       <action type="SEND_KEYS">Control+Alt+Down</action>
   </gesture>

   <gesture type="DRAG" fingers="3" direction="RIGHT">
       <action type="SEND_KEYS">Control+Alt+Left</action>
   </gesture>

   <gesture type="DRAG" fingers="3" direction="LEFT">
       <action type="SEND_KEYS">Control+Alt+Right</action>
   </gesture>
   ```

Hope this help !

---

Source for the xprofile: [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchegg)